# Starting a long running process on a server from a WSGI application

Tags: python, wsgi

I need to start a long running process (30 min) via http and get status as it's running. The "process" is basically a Python script that updates a database. I have the following constraints:

1. Only one instance of the process can run at a time.
2. The WSGI application is running in several interpreters, so I can't just make a global variable isRunning to keep track of it.
3. I need a web page to track the process (status/progress)
4. No Django, just pure WSGI.

Anyone have any experiences doing the same thing?

Comment: Can you clarify how #1 and #2 do not contradict each other?

Comment: The "process" or job is entirely separate from the WSGI application. The WSGI application is running in 4 processes/interpreters using modwsgi and WSGIDaemonProcess processes=4 for robustness/speed.

Answer (score 2):

Isolate the process as a separate daemon, and use MQ or some other IPC to hand it jobs. Have it update a value in a database as it progresses, and read that value in a web page.

Comment: The process spits out a log, I could save that to a file and read it from a web page. How would I use a python script as a daemon?

Answer (score 1):

Look at using Celery (http://celeryproject.org/) and run the task outside of the Python web application processes.